# Google Analytics - View filter not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I have a Google Analytics account for a mobile app (it is actually a .NET Desktop application that is hooked up to the API for mobile apps).

To get rid of referral spam etc, I've set up an include-filter for my view (see pic below). The filter checks the Application Name field and should include only traffic that has this field. In my application, I always call the GA API with this application name.

Now, the problem is that this filter seems to not work when set as a View Filter (to filter out incoming traffic). Even though I set this filter up several weeks ago, I still get referral spam traffic that does not have a valid Application Name. But if I apply the exact same filter to my reports, it actually filters out the spam.

[image: GA View Filter]

Does anyone here have an idea of why the filter works when filtering out reports, but not as a view filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by including a hostname filter. The filter is set as:
Include -> Hostname -> Filter Pattern "(not set)".